# как фильтровать по неделям?

Tags: python, django

у меня есть такая модель

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='user_report')
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='report')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    edited_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

так вот мне надо эту модель фильтровать по неделям т.е в итоге у меня должно быть так, первая неделя года столько-то Report вторая неделя столько-то и т.д
я конечно могу сделать вручную, но это получется не красиво я хочу чтоб вместо меня сделала это БД.

Comment: я пробовал так по месяцам у меня получилось


truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month, 'created_date')
    object_date = Profile.objects.extra({'date': truncate_date})
    report = object_date.values('date', 'user_report__stat_report__name').filter(
        id=profiles_id).annotate(
        Sum('user_report__stat_report__value')).order_by('date')

Comment: Я бы просто завёл ещё одно поле `week` в модели

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django ORM не умеет группировать по неделям. Посчитать группировку по дням легко:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Report.objects.values('created_date').annotate(Count('id'))
```

По неделям либо программно, либо SQL запросами без участия ORM, если СУБД это поддерживает. Типа такого:

```
SELECT WEEK('created_date') AS 'week', COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM appname_report GROUP BY week ORDER BY week
```

Comment: вот именно я пробовал, и по SQL запросу там тоже нету такого!
а вручную делать как то не очень то красиво!

Comment: Какуб СУБД вы используете?

Comment: База данных Mysql

Comment: Как же нету? Есть `SELECT WEEK('created_date') AS 'week', COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM appname_report GROUP BY week ORDER BY week`

Comment: Спасибо большое выручили)

Comment: Для спасибо можете принять ответ.

Comment: Чувак, если ответ действительно правильный, то его нужно помечать галочкой как правильный.

Comment: Окей принял вопрос

Comment: @ilgizkasymov давайте продолжим обсуждение [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46572/discussion-on-question-by-ilgiz-kasymov----). Предыдущие 3 комментария лучше удалить.